# notepad++ how to keep all the line start with # and delete the rest of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I kinda know how to keep delete all line start with # with the code

```
^[#].*
```

But I wonder how to do the reverse? keep all the line start with # and delete the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you just use negated character class in your regex:

```
^[^#].+
```

`[^#]` means match everything except `#`, so please see picture below for better understanding:
[image]

Then just replace all, this will empty lines. So then you need to match new line characters only with `^\r\n` (depending on operation system, it could be also `^\n`) and again replace it with empty string:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: If answer helped you, please mark it as accepted (green check mark on the left).